# Receiving POST data with Java Spring

Tags: java, arrays, spring, list, post

I'm trying to catch an array that has been posted to my Java Controller with the code shown below:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/json/foo.json")
public @ResponseBody Object foo(List<Integer> fooIds)
{
    for (Integer id : fooIds)
    {
         fooService.delete(id);
    }
    return null;
}
```

However I keep getting the following error:

```
Could not instantiate bean class [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface
```

The array I am posting is setup as follows (in PHP):

```
$array = array(
    "fooIds[0]" => 1,
    "fooIds[1]" => 2,
    "fooIds[2]" => 3,
    "fooIds[3]" => 4,
    "fooIds[4]" => 5,
);
```

Originally I tried:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: Don't change the title to `[solved]`, accept an answer to mark it as solved

Comment: I can't accept my own answer for two days... so I was marking it as solved for a temporary measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it to working with the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/json/foo.json")
public @ResponseBody Object foo(@RequestParam("ids") int[] fooIds)
{
    for (Integer id : fooIds)
    {
        fooService.delete(id);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The array is then setup like this:

```
$array = array(
    'fooIds' => '1,2,3,4,5',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ArrayList instead of List. Many tools have problems like that, so that they do not know what class to instantiate, when List is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a concrete implementation of an array you want, like `public @ResponseBody Object foo(ArrayList<Integer> fooIds)` or define a converter.

Comment: That gave me an ArrayList variable but it was still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your method signature to `public @ResponseBody Object foo(int[] fooIds)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Could not instantiate bean class [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface.
```

Indicates you should use an class implementing List for example ArrayList

try writing

```
new List<Object>() // the compiler will complain
new ArrayList<Object>() // the compiler will not complain
```

Comment: Using ArrayList stops the error... but the array itself is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only problem in your code is that you should annotate the List with @RequestParam

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/json/foo.json")
public @ResponseBody Object foo(@RequestParam("ids") List<Integer> fooIds)
{
    for (Integer id : fooIds)
    {
         fooService.delete(id);
    }
    return null;
}
```